# configure aws ec2 wait timeout option

Tags: aws-cli

Is there an option or a setting somewhere to control the timeout for an `aws ec2 wait` command?
  Or the number of attempts or waiting period between attempts?

I want to be able to `aws ec2 wait instance-terminated` for some instances I'm quickly spinning up to perform a few task then terminating.  It times out on some longer running tasks with "Waiter InstanceTerminated failed: Max attempts exceeded".

I can't seem to find any info anywhere. I've grepped the cli source code, but my knowledge of Python is too limited for me to understand what's going on.  I see there might be something in [this test](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/blob/develop/tests/unit/customizations/test_waiters.py#L112) using maxAttempts and delay, but can't figure out how to leverage that from the cli.

So far my suboptimal solution is to sleep first, then start the wait.

Comment: You're right -- I did a test and it eventually timed-out. I guess it's designed to be used immediately after issuing a Stop command, rather than waiting for some long-running process to finish.

Answer (score 1):

There is not a timeout option in the AWS CLI, but you can just use the native `timeout` command from coreutils to do what you want.

```
timeout 10 aws ec2 wait instance-terminated
```

will abort if the command does not return within 10 seconds. A timeout will automatically return error code 124, otherwise it returns the error code of the command.

Comment: I think that might work if a shorter timeout was desired, but I wanted to have the timeout be longer than the default aws cli.  That said, I haven't tested this to verify.

Answer (score 0):

There's an open Github issue about adding configurable parameters https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/1295

You can also find some environment variables you can define here

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/topic/config-vars.html

One of them being `AWS_MAX_ATTEMPTS Number of total requests`

But for my use case (restore dynamo table from snapshot) does not seem to be working